How Can I Retrieve Refresh_token from Big Commerce?
I have the following code to get Access token and it returns access token, but tje response contains not refresh token. What could be the reason?
$token_url = 'https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token';
$post_data = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'code' => $code,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
];


Searching further, I got the information that BigCommerce access tokens are generally long-lived, meaning they do not expire frequently. You might not need a refresh token if your access token is valid for an extended period.

You have any other sources other than chatGPT?

This following code helps you to fetch the access token from the BigCommerce OAuth2 response and checks for the presence of a refresh token. Make sure that your sensitive data should be loaded from the Environment variables
$token_url = 'https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token';

$post_data = [
    'client_id' => getenv('BIGCOMMERCE_CLIENT_ID'), // Load from environment variable
    'client_secret' => getenv('BIGCOMMERCE_CLIENT_SECRET'), // Load from environment variable
    'code' => $code,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
];

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Check for cURL errors
if ($error) {
    echo 'Error retrieving token: ' . $error . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

// Decode the JSON response
$response_data = json_decode($response, true);

// Check for JSON decoding errors
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo 'Error decoding JSON response: ' . json_last_error_msg() . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

// Handle the response
if (isset($response_data['access_token'])) {
    $access_token = $response_data['access_token'];
    echo 'Access Token: ' . $access_token . PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($response_data['refresh_token'])) {
        $refresh_token = $response_data['refresh_token'];
        echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $refresh_token . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Refresh Token not provided in the response.' . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    // Handle error from BigCommerce (check for error codes in response)
    echo 'Error retrieving access token: ' . (isset($response_data['error']) ? $response_data['error'] : $response) . PHP_EOL;
}


BigCommerce OAuth2 implementation might not always include a refresh token in the initial response. It depends on your application configuration and permission requested.

Please explain how this wall of code would solve the issue OP is experiencing...

@DarkBee  Yes, it addresses the issue of fetching and handling the access token in a right manner. Please review the complete code

From what I've reviewed it only shows a message Refresh Token not provided in the response when it's not available, so how does it solve the issue then? Furthermore code-only answers are not good answers.

Nowhere in the Bigcommerce api documentation it says about refresh_token.
